# Pandas DateTime index, assign value to column based on based on time AND day filter

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dayofweek

Im trying to assign a value to a column based on a day and time filter.
Lets say I create a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

date_range = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(date(2019,8,30), date.today(), freq='15T')})
date_range.index = date_range['date']
```

I can then filter for the day (Sunday) and assign a value:

```
date_range['Happy Hour'] = ((pd.DatetimeIndex(date_range.index).dayofweek) // 6 == 'Yes!!')
```

and I can also filter a timeframe and assign a value

```
date_range.loc[date_range.between_time('15:00','18:59').index, 'Happy Hour'] = 'Yes!!'
```

But surely there is an easy way to combine these into one line of code so every Sunday between 15:00 and 19:00 the Happy Hour column gets filled with 'Yes!!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter Sundays and then filter times by:

```
idx = date_range[date_range.index.dayofweek == 6].between_time('15:00','18:59').index
date_range.loc[idx, 'Happy Hour'] = 'Yes!!'
print (date_range)
```

Comment: So obvious now...thanks for that jezrael!